# What to wear in Ireland at winter

Tags: gear, clothing, seasonal, ireland, winter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Winter apparel for Europe Nov - Dec 11](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2643/winter-apparel-for-europe-nov-dec-11)

I will be in Ireland (Galway) for November and December. What should I wear?

P.S.: Where I live, it never goes below 10°C.

Comment: See if [this question about winter travel in Europe in November and December](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2643/winter-apparel-for-europe-nov-dec-11) addresses your concerns. If not, please add more details to this question to highlight why the other question doesn't address your issues.

Comment: This question seems a bit more specific and Ireland was not mentioned in the other question so specific answers could still be useful to some people (if only to confirm that it's similar). Briefly: Ireland, especially the West coast is really not that cold compared to Central Europe. You will see palm trees in open ground, it's seldom freezing. However, the climate is not Mediterranean either so if you come from a tropical country you do need warm things. Above all, be prepared for rain, everyday. That, and the wind, can make you feel colder so headgear and gloves are probably in order too.

Comment: I don't think its correct